# Move files in S3 using oozie

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want to move files in S3 using AWS oozie. I want to run

```
aws s3 mv s3://temp/*.zip s3://temp/processed_files/. --recursive
```

How I can do this in oozie?

### EDIT 1

```
2015-11-12 10:18:55,758  WARN ShellActionExecutor:542 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[rad_workflow] JOB[0000118-151029144311676-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000118-151029144311676-oozie-oozi-W@sh] Launcher exception: Cannot run program "move.sh" (in directory "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1446129655727_0421/container_1446129655727_0421_01_000002"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "move.sh" (in directory "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1446129655727_0421/container_1446129655727_0421_01_000002"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain.execute(ShellMain.java:93)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain.run(ShellMain.java:55)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain.main(ShellMain.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:171)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:166)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 17 more

2015-11-12 10:18:55,838  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[rad_workflow] JOB[0000118-151029144311676-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000118-151029144311676-oozie-oozi-W@sh] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2015-11-12 10:18:55,880  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[rad_workflow] JOB[0000118-151029144311676-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000118-151029144311676-oozie-oozi-W@killemail] Start action [0000118-151029144311676-oozie-oozi-W@killemail] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
```

[image]

Screen shot of Hue Oozie screen shot and error log.

Answer (score 1):

if you did what Helmut Zechmann said and it's still not working, check that the problem is not linked to your shell script which has windows line endings instead of unix one.

try to convert it in the correct format using notepad++ or another tool.

Answer (score 0):

Write a java class to move files in s3 and implement it as a java action in oozie.

Comment: Can't we write an shell action for it. Write a shell script and use it in shell action. I tried this and getting file not found exception. Any idea???

Comment: Without providing the actual scripts and the actual error stack, it's like asking *"what is the meaning of life?"* and expecting someone to boldly answer *"42"*.

Comment: If someone understood what a shell script is and my question is clear. Then without guessing the meaning of life or age of person, one can easily apply life expectancy algo. Well, I will provide full error stack in few hours.

Comment: A shell action runs in yarn on your datanodes. So if you put the script into hdfs then copy it out with “<file>bin/move.sh#move.sh<file>” the next problem will be “aws command not found” as that tool wont be installed on every node in your cluster. Installing that on every node is probably a bad idea - you will have a software version nightmare later. yarn installs a security manager on the jvm blocking reading local files. A dev can write a java main class that has aws jars and calls aws commands. You can add the correct jar to the classpath easily and security manager will let you run it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that oozie cannot find your script. Put your script into hdfs and provide an alies for the script using the file element of the shell action:

```
<file>hdfs://path/to/move.sh#move.sh</file>
```

This creates an alias from the hdfs path to the name provided after the `#`, in this case move.sh.
Now you can reference move.sh in the `exec` element of your script.

See https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/DG_ShellActionExtension.html for reference.